# Soft keyboard not hidden when Done clicked in AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have several `EditText` in my app, and when the "Done" key is clicked the soft keyboard is hidden. This does not happen with `AutocompleteTextView`.

Any idea why? Is there anything more to do to get the same behaviour with `AutocompleteTextView`?

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/search_zip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/submit"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/city_or_zip"
    android:background="@drawable/bt_grey"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

or in java code:

```
InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);    
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: For some reason, none of the other methods worked for me... except `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Comment: Try this line dude...It will work..!! inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 0):

In my case `setOnEditorActionListener` was issue. So I removed below code :

```
searchEditText?.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {
                return@setOnEditorActionListener true
            } else
                return@setOnEditorActionListener false
        }
```